# Pandas convert datatime format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe with a column of datetime object with the following format:

```
df['TIME_M']=pd.to_datetime(df['TIME_M'],format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

However, at the same time, I also want a column of datetime with the following format (without the %f):

```
%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S
```

Can I covert from the datetime object `%s` to the one without `%s` in a fast way?

Currently I am using the following code:

```
df['TIME_S']=df.TIME_M.map(lambda t:t.strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

However, it seems that converting to string is a rather slow operation for pandas. I was wondering if there is a fast way to make the conversion, while keeping the output of the conversion as a datetime object?

P.S. Assume that I already have `df['TIME_M']` in format `%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First if need datetimes format is a bif different like need - `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

If need datetimes without `%f` add [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html):

```
df['TIME_M'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME_M'], format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f').dt.floor('s')
#if datetimes column
#df['TIME_M'] = df['TIME_M'].dt.floor('s')
```

Or convert to numpy values ant then seconds:

```
df['TIME_M'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME_M'],format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f').values.astype('datetime64[s]')
#if datetimes column
#df['TIME_M'] = df['TIME_M'].values.astype('datetime64[s]')
```

Or split in list comprehension:

```
df['TIME_M'] = pd.to_datetime([x.split('.')[0] for x in df['TIME_M']], format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Timings in sample data:

```
N = 100000
df = pd.DataFrame({'TIME_M':['20190913 04:04:20'] * N})
df['TIME_M'] +=  ['.{}'.format(x) for x in range(1, len(df)+1)] 


df['TIME_M1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME_M'],format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f').dt.floor('s')
df['TIME_M2'] = pd.to_datetime([x.split('.')[0] for x in df['TIME_M']], format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
df['TIME_M3'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME_M'],format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f').values.astype('datetime64[s]')

#print (df)

In [180]: %timeit df['TIME_M3'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME_M'],format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f').values.astype('datetime64[s]')
28.2 ms ± 358 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [181]: %timeit df['TIME_M1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME_M'],format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f').dt.floor('s')
28.7 ms ± 208 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [182]: %timeit df['TIME_M2'] = pd.to_datetime([x.split('.')[0] for x in df['TIME_M']], format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
69 ms ± 1.81 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Thanks for another 2 solutions, @Anton vBR:

```
In [187]: %timeit df['TIME_M4'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME_M'].str[:17], format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
58 ms ± 709 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [188]: %timeit df['TIME_M5'] = pd.to_datetime([x[:17] for x in df['TIME_M']], format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
45.6 ms ± 536 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood. It seems OP already has datetime objects in which case: `df['TIME_M'] = df['TIME_M'].dt.floor('s')` would be enough. Not 100% sure though.